# you are not a member of this organization . MS CRM 2016 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am facing one  issue  while user logging in CRM online 2016 instance.

issue is "You are not a  member of this organization".

only for two users we are  getting the issue. Users has  been created in crm ,Roles has been assigned to user as well.

any help  would  be  appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about the license ?

Comment: Hi Alex..Licenses are already  there .Still we are facing the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like they are already loggen on with a different account in the same browser. Does the issue persist if the users open a new InPrivate (IE)/Incognito (Chrome)/Anonymous(Firefox) browser window and try to log in ?

Comment: Checked in private IE & Firefox window. but No luck.

Comment: is the user showing up in the list of Active users in CRM?

Comment: Yes  ,User  showing up  in active users view